# Calculating sum of ascii values of a char

Tags: c++, char, sum, ascii

I need to create a hash function that is supposed to return the sum of the ASCII values mod by 100(which is HASH_TABLE_SIZE) in a given char, but I don't seem to be getting the correct output. How do I correct this?

```
int string_set::hash_function(const char *s) {

int h = 0;
for (int i =0; i < *s; i++)
{
    h = h + int(s[i]);
    return h % HASH_TABLE_SIZE;
}
return h;
}
```

Comment: What *is* the "correct" output?

Comment: What this `i < *s` supposed to mean?

Comment: for example hash_function("a") should return 97 , and hash_function("ab") would return 95

Comment: i < *s is supposed to be such that i is less than the length of the char *s

Comment: What is "the length of the char *s"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not `return` in the middle of process.

Try this:

```
int string_set::hash_function(const char *s) {

    int h = 0;
    for (int i =0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) // the loop condition didn't seem good
    {
        // the cast to unsigned char may be needed for system in which the type char is signed
        h = (h + (unsigned char)s[i]) % HASH_TABLE_SIZE;
    }
    return h;
}
```

This code will work well only if your system use ASCII code as character code for `char`.

Comment: The `int` cast is redundant, integer promotions makes that same conversion anyway